# How to automatically make the maximum of each row in a table(grid) bold?

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation, grid-layouts

```
TableForm[Table[i/j + 4*Boole[j > i] // N, {i, 3}, {j, 4}], TableHeadings -> {{"Row1", "Row2", "Row3"}, {"Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"}}]
```

Produces the following table:

[image]

How select the maximum value in each row and make it a bold font?

So that `4.5`, `4.66667` and `4.75` are bold in the 1st, 2nd and 3rd row.

Thanks

Comment: related: [nicely print out a matrix in mathematica](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966007/nicely-print-out-a-matrix-in-mathematica)

Comment: @WReach Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   TableForm[ (m = Max[#];   (#  /. m :> Style[m, Red] ) ) & /@ 
        Table[i/j + 4*Boole[j > i] // N, {i, 3}, {j, 4}] ,
        TableHeadings -> {{"Row1", "Row2", "Row3"}, {"Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"}}]
```

[image]

Red is easier to see but Bold works as well..

Comment: Very nice, Thanks!

Comment: Yes, red is better. But I am think I am going to export the table for publishing. So I might avoid color.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another realization of the straightforward idea

```
t = Table[i/j + 4*Boole[j > i] // N, {i, 3}, {j, 4}];
h = {{"Row1", "Row2", "Row3"}, {"Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"}};

Style[TableForm[# /. x : Max@# :> Style[x, Bold] & /@ t, 
  TableHeadings -> h], FontFamily -> "Times"]
```

[image]

I change `FontFamily` for better visibility

Comment: i knew there was a cleaner way to do that..

Comment: Is there a way to get the same column-wise instead of row-wise?

Answer (score 1):

Using `Position` with `MapAt`:

```
ClearAll[sF];
sF = With[{pos = Thread[{Range@Length@#, Position[#, Max@#][[1, 1]] & /@ #}]},
          MapAt[Style[#, Bold, Red] &, #, pos]] &;

t = Table[i/j + 4*Boole[j > i] // N, {i, 3}, {j, 4}];
h = {{"Row1", "Row2", "Row3"}, {"Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"}};
TableForm[sF@t, TableHeadings -> h]
```

[image]

... with `ReplacePart`:

```
ClearAll[sF2];
sF2 = With[{m=#, pos = Thread[{Range@Length@#, Position[#, Max@#][[1, 1]] & /@ #}]},
           ReplacePart[m, (# -> Style[m[[## & @@ #]], Bold, Red]) & /@ pos]] &;

TableForm[sF2@t, TableHeadings -> h]
(* same picture *)
```

... with `Part` assignment:

```
ClearAll[sF3];
sF3 = Module[{r=#, p = Position[#, Max@#][[1]]},
             (r[[#]] = Style[r[[#]], Bold, Red]) & /@ p; r] & /@ # &;

TableForm[sF3@t, TableHeadings -> h]
(* same picture *)
```